# R, issue "unable to load shared object cairo.so" on Linux CentOS 7

Tags: r, heatmap, cairo

I've been using R with ggplot2 and other packages on my Linux CentOS 7 for a long time.
Today, all of a sudden, it stopped working.

When I call the `png()` function in my script, it generates the following errrors:

```
Warning messages:
1: In png(heatmap_file) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
  /lib64/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates
2: In png(heatmap_file) : failed to load cairo DLL
```

I tried to update the cairo package many times but nothing worked out so far.
What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and I am going to share it with the community.

I am working on a Dell Latitude 3540 laptop running Linux CentOS 7 operating system (centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64).

I ran `sudo yum -y update` and I understood there was a duplication issue regarding the `freetype` package, which was installed twice, and some other packages that were having conflicts.

I then removed the old freetype package and the conflicting packages with this command:

```
rpm -e freetype-2.4.11-12.el7.i686 --nodeps
rpm -e conflicting-package-1 --nodeps
rpm -e conflicting-package-2 --nodeps
...
```

Then I updated all the packages I manually removed:

```
sudo yum -y update freetype
sudo yum -y conflicting-package-1 freetype
sudo yum -y conflicting-package-2 freetype
...
```

This method worked out for me; I hope it might be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of cairo (`/lib64/libcairo.so.2`) depends on a function called `FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates`. This function should come from FreeType. However, your version of `libfreetype.so` seems to be older and does not have this symbol. So, either you explicitly installed an older version, or "something" comes with an older version of FreeType.

I would look for files called `libfreetype.so` and check if they have the necessary symbol

I'm on Debian testing and here I get (this means that my version of FreeType does have this symbol; you would get no output if the symbol is not available):

```
$ nm -s -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so | grep FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates                                                                           
000000000001d260 T FT_Get_Var_Design_Coordinates
```

For you, based on the path to `libcairo.so`, I would expect something like `/lib64/libfreetype.so` to be the path to check.